# Calculator in NASM

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, dos, dosbox

I'm trying to write calculator in NASM (Asembly). It doesn't show any errors but somehow after I enter two numbers to add them, program simply stuck. Can't do anything after that.

Here's code:

```
org 100h

_start:
;LOGO
mov ah, 9
mov dx, logo1
int 21h

mov ah, 9
mov dx, logo2
int 21h


;MENU
mov ah, 9
mov dx, ramka1
int 21h

mov ah, 9
mov dx, wybor
int 21h

mov ah, 9
mov dx, dzialanie1
int 21h

mov ah, 9
mov dx, dzialanie2
int 21h

mov ah, 9
mov dx, dzialanie3
int 21h

mov ah, 9
mov dx, dzialanie4
int 21h

mov ah, 9
mov dx, dzialanie5
int 21h

mov ah, 9
mov dx, ramka2
int 21h

mov ah, 9
mov dx, nwln
int 21h


; WYBOR DZIALANIA
mov ah, 0
int 16h

cmp al, '1' 
je dodawanie 

cmp al, '5'
je wyjscie


dodawanie:

mov ah, 9
mov dx, zmienna1
int 21h

mov ah, 0ah
mov dx, bufor
int 21h

lea si, [bufor + 2] 
mov cx, 0
mov cl, [bufor + 1]
call tekst_na_liczbe

mov [liczba1], ax

mov ah, 9
mov dx, nwln
int 21h

mov ah, 9
mov dx, zmienna2
int 21h

mov ah, 0ah
mov dx, bufor
int 21h

lea si, [bufor + 2]
mov cx, 0
mov cl, [bufor + 1]
call tekst_na_liczbe

add ax, [liczba1]

mov di, liczba
call liczbe_na_tekst

mov bl, '$'
mov bx,ax
mov [bx+liczba], bl

mov ah, 9
mov dx, wynik
int 21h

mov ah, 9
mov dx, liczba
int 21h

mov ah, 9
mov dx, nwln
int 21h

mov ah, 9
mov dx, nwln
int 21h

jmp _start


;WYJSCIE
wyjscie:

mov ax, 4C00h
int 21h

zmienna1 db "||Podaj pierwsza liczbe: $"

bufor db 15
db 0
times 15 db '$'

liczba db 15
db 0
times 15 db '$'

zmienna2 db "||Podaj druga liczbe: $"

liczba1 dd 0
liczba2 dd 0

wynik db 10, 13, "//Wynik: $"

nwln db 10, 13, '$'

menu db "Wybierz dzialanie:", 10, 13, 10, 13, '$'

;WYSWIETLENIE LOGO I MENU
logo1 db      "==============================================", 10, 13, "$"
logo2 db      "||Kalkulator w ASM                          ||", 10, 13, "$"
ramka1 db     "==============================================", 10, 13, "$"
wybor db      "||Wybierz dzialanie:                        ||", 10, 13, "$"
dzialanie1 db "||1.Dodawanie                               ||", 10, 13, "$"
dzialanie2 db "||2.Odejmowanie                             ||", 10, 13, "$"
dzialanie3 db "||3.Mnozenie                                ||", 10, 13, "$"
dzialanie4 db "||4.Dzielenie                               ||", 10, 13, "$"
dzialanie5 db "||5.Wyjcie z kalkulatora                    ||", 10, 13, "$"
ramka2 db     "==============================================", "$"



liczbe_na_tekst:
push cx
push dx
push si
mov cx, 10 
mov si, 0 
.dziel:
mov dx, 0 
div cx 
add dl, '0' 
mov bp,di
add di,si
mov dl,[bp]
inc si 
cmp ax, 1
jge .dziel 
push esi 
dec esi 
mov ecx, 0 
.odwroc:
mov bx, di 
mov di, cx 
add di, cx 
mov al,[bx] 
inc cx 
dec si
cmp cx, si
jl .odwroc 
pop ax 
pop dx
pop cx
ret


tekst_na_liczbe:
push bx
push dx
mov ax, 0 
mov bx, 0 
.petla:
mov dx, 10 
mul dx 
mov dl, [si+bx] 
sub dl, '0' 
add ax, dx 
inc bx 
cmp bx, cx 
jl .petla 
pop dx
pop bx
ret
```

I'm sorry, parts of code are in polish language but overall should be understand. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: It looks like you may have inadvertently stripped out all the comments from the code before uploading it ?

Comment: Use a debugger to step through the code.

Comment: @Inver: Just out a curiosity,are you really running it in the MS-DOS operating system or just on virtual machine/DOS-emulator?

Comment: I'm using DosBox, the same one to play old games ;).

Answer (score 1):

As there are absolutely no comments, it's difficult to understand what's going on.

In `liczbe_na_tekst` function, in the beginning you push `cx`, `dx` and `si`, but in the end you pop `ax`, `dx`, `cx`. Before `call liczbe_na_tekst` `si` seems to contain an address to your buffer. In the end of `liczbe_na_tekst` it gets passed to `ax`.

After `dodawanie` label:

```
dodawanie:
 ...
lea si, [bufor + 2]
...
call liczbe_na_tekst

mov bl, '$'
mov bx,ax
```

Here, you first write `'$'` to `bl` but immediately owerwrite `bx` with `ax` (losing `'$'` that you stored in `bl` just one instruction earlier). `bx` contains now the address of `bufor + 2` (originally from `lea si, [bufor + 2]`), and then instead of `'$'`, `bl` contains now the low 8 bits of address of `bufor + 2`.

```
mov [bx+liczba], bl
```

Then, here you write to `[bufor+liczba+2]` the low 8 bits of the address of `bufor + 2`, not `'$'`. `bx` contains here the address of of `bufor + 2`.

I think this is not what you intend to do. Probably your code crashes then when you modify the code of `liczbe_na_tekst` or `tekst_na_liczbe` (as you sum the addresses `bufor` and `liczba`, and subfunctions `liczbe_na_tekst` and `tekst_na_liczbe` are after your data in the memory)`, and the program crashes as CPU reaches an illegal instruction or it gets in an infinite loop.

I think you need to fix at the least the following parts:

The `push` and `pop` instructions of `liczbe_na_tekst`:

```
liczbe_na_tekst:
    push ax
    push cx
    push dx
    push si
    ...
    pop si
    pop dx
    pop cx
    pop ax
    ret
```

Then after `call liczbe_na_tekst`:

```
mov bx,ax
mov [bx+liczba], byte '$'
```

Some other fixes may also be needed. Haven't tested.

Comment: Thanks A LOT nrz I'll test it out asap ;D

Answer (score 1):

This is probably not an "answer"... not "the" answer anyway... but it looks "wrong" to me.

```
; WYBOR DZIALANIA
mov ah, 0
int 16h

cmp al, '1' 
je dodawanie 

cmp al, '5'
je wyjscie


dodawanie:
```

If the input is '5' exactly, we go to `wyjscie` (Polish for "exit"?). Any other input - including but not limited to '1' - we "fall through" to `dodawanie`. Is this what you intend?

Comment: Hah true. 2,3,4 are for rest of operations. For now I'm focused only on adding numbers, if this will work I'll make rest.

Comment: Okay. Focus on the issue(s) nrz has identified. Good catch, nrz!

Comment: dodawanie means addition